# Resolving a condition that requires Boolean but found Boolean?

Tags: kotlin

`Kotlin 1.4.0`

Resolving a condition that requires Boolean but found Boolean?

I have the following code:

```
detailList.firstOrNull()?.postCode.takeIf { postcode: String? ->
    postcode?.run { this != ZERO }
}?.also { postcode ->
    view.editTextPostcode.setText(postcode)
}
```

Here I get an error that says `required Boolean found Boolean?`

As postcode could be null, I am wondering why its not smart casted to a non-null.

This works by removing the safe call operator

```
detailList.firstOrNull()?.postCode.takeIf { postcode: String? ->
    postcode.run { this != ZERO }
}?.also { postcode ->
    view.editTextPostcode.setText(postcode)
}
```

In the above, wouldn't this crash if postcode really is null?

This is the code I have used as I check for null and then evaluate the second condition:

```
detailList.firstOrNull()?.postCode.takeIf { postcode: String? ->
        postcode != null && postcode != ZERO            
}?.also { postcode ->
        view.editTextPostcode.setText(postcode)
}
```

As `@Steyrix` noticed in his comment if the postcode is really null then there is no evaluation of the condition.

This is the update that will evaluate the condition and return a true boolean. If postcode is null then it will return false

```
detailList.firstOrNull()?.postCode.takeIf { postcode: String? ->
    postcode?.run {
        postcode != ZERO
    } ?: false         
}?.also { postcode ->
    view.editTextPostcode.setText(postcode)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it not smart-casted to a non-null in the first case because you explicitly declare it as a variable of nullable type? If the post code can be null, there can be no boolean expression evaluation, so there can be no boolean.

Comment: That makes sense what you said and updated my question with a possible solution. There can only be a boolean returned if postcode is non-null. if the postcode is null there is no evaluation. However, just one question. If the postcode is null it will skip the evaluation, in that case why does the IDE say required `Boolean but found Boolean? ` I would have thought it would have found `Unit` as nothing is returned  as the last statment? thanks

Comment: It happens because performing of typed method on a nullable instance will return null if the instance is actually null. E.g. `object?.intMethod` will return null as `Int?`. `object?.boolMethod` will return null as `Boolean?`. Since there is no nullable Unit, compiler defines type as the nullable return type of a method.

Comment: @Steyrix can you create that as an answer so I can mark this question as resolved

Comment: yeah, sure. I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the original question:

`postCode` is actually not being smart-casted to non-null type, since it is explicitly declared as a variable of nullable type. Evaluation of boolean expression will not happen, when `postCode` will be null. Since there can be no evaluation, there can be no `Boolean` but `Boolean?` instead.

The reason of the return type is not being `Unit` is that performing of typed method on a nullable instance returns null if the instance is null as well. However, null can represent different types depending on method's return type.

E.g. when having a nullable instance `object`:

Since the instance is null, calling member methods/fields will return null.
`object?.intMethod()` will return null as `Int?` and `object?.boolMethod()` will return null as `Boolean?`

In your case compiler defines actual return type of `takeIf` as the nullable return type of `run` which is `Boolean?`, since latter method returns result of boolean expression evaluation.